# Aurelia bi-directional value converter for input

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I am trying to write a value converter for numeric input. In the `fromView()` it strips no-numeric characters and returns parsed value. And in `toView()` it formats the value using `aurelia-i18n`. This valueconverter is bind to a `input type=text` field.

The `fromView()` works correctly, and it seems that `toView()` also should have worked correctly if invoked in a different order.

Here is my value converter:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework"
import {I18N, NfValueConverter} from "aurelia-i18n";

export class NumericValueConverter {
    static inject = [I18N];
    constructor(private i18N: I18N) {}

    toView(value: any, elementId: any, config: any) {
        let retval = "";
        if (value) {
            const nf = this.i18N.nf(undefined, "de");
            retval = nf.format(value);
        }            
        return retval;
    }

    fromView(value: any, elementId: any, config: any) {
        let retval = "";
        if (value) {
            retval = Here_Goes_The_Logic_To_Strip_Non_NumericChar_And_Parse_ToNumber
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    <input id="${someId}"
       if.bind="someCondition"
       type="text"
       class="form-control"
       value.bind="targetObj[objProp]| numeric:config"
       readonly.bind="isreadonlyview">
```

The value coming from `toView()` is never reflected in the `input` field. Any suggestion why?

**My observation so far**

- `toView()` is called before `fromView()`. However I think if the order was different it could've worked.
- However, for the first time of changing value in the `input` causes following calls respectively:`toView()`, `fromView()`, `toView()`. And thus for the first time it works but not for the subsequent times, as then the calls are just this: `toView()`, `fromView()`.
- I also thought of getting rid of the `toView()` from the value converter and use `NfValueConverter`, comes with `aurelia-i18n`, but that too have exactly the same effect like this.